# Yii отправка форм

Tags: php, yii, form

Как на `yii`  сделать такое:

Есть форма регистрации компании и есть `input file`. Как сделать так, чтобы при валидации ошибок после редиректа на страницу регистрации картинки, которые выбрали, не удалялись.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, необходимо сохранить файл при обновлении страницы, в случае когда данные с полей не валидные?

Comment: Если да, то как вариант продублировать валидацию на сторону клиента, с помощью `JavaScript` или вообще `HTML5` и не давать пользователю отправлять данные пока данные не валидные, если есть такая возможность.

Comment: Да правильно поняли ситуация, но именно такое нужен то что написал ))